# Change sans serif font in Koma Script?

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, sans-serif

I am using `scrbook` of KOMA-Script.

I want to change the font of the chapter/section headings (i.e. `disposition`) of my document. However, changing the font of `sfdefault` does not work.

I must uncomment `\setkomafont{disposition}{\ubun}` for the font change to take effect.

I wonder how KOMA defines its sans serif fonts and why only changing `sfdefault` won't work?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,bibtotoc,DIV=11,BCOR=6mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{roboto}

\usepackage{ blindtext}

%\setkomafont{disposition}{roboto}
\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{roboto}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `roboto` automatically changes the default sans serif font to `roboto`. KOMA-Script just uses `\sffamily` in the `disposition`, so you have to do nothing. Remove `\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{roboto}` in the MWE and the headings appear in `roboto`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! 

What if I am loading my custom font (e.g. using fontspec package & \newfontfamily) and have to change the default sans serif font manually?

Comment: With `fontspec` I would define the default sans font with `\setsansfont{⟨font⟩}[⟨font features⟩]`.